# How to get images side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my images to lay under my text so they are side by side horizontally. I've tried messing around with it in CSS but nothing seems to be working. Is there something that I'm missing? Any help will be greatly appreciated! I inserted a picture of what my page currently looks like and you can see that my images are lining up to the left of my split screen vertically. I am trying to get them so they are horizontally lined side by side underneath my text.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0C133C;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav>li {
  display: Inline-block;
  padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;
}

.nav>li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0C133C;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;

}

.clearer {
  clear: both;
}

.subnav class {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.subnav>div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0C133C;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px 30px 10px 9px;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.subnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 1rem;

}

.split {
  height: 70%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -50;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.centered{
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 125px;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   text-align: center;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #282C41;
  color: white;
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 40px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

p {
font-size: 30;
}



.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
  margin-top: .5rem;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  position: relative;
  left: 140px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button: {
  position: relative;
  left: 140px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"
    

</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>
        

<subnav class="subnav subnav-light bg-light">
<img src="universallogo.jpg" class="logo"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="subnav=brand" href="#">
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Bonds</a>
</a>
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Report a Claim</a>
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About Us</a>
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Search</a>
</div>
</subnav>
 

<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
    <h1>GET YOUR LICENSE & PERMIT BONDS FAST & EASY</h1>
    <p>We provide our Customers with a fast, easy, and secure way to get bonded. Get your Free Quote in minutes.
</p>
  </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="Demotech.jpg" alt="rating" style="width:40%" "height: 20%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="USTreasury.jpg" alt="treas" style="width:40%">
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="split right">


<form name="form1" id="form1" action="/action_page.php">
  <select name="subject" id="subject">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your State</option>
      <option value="California">California</option>
      <option value="California">Illinois</option>
      <option value="California">Michigan</option>
      <option value="California">Ohio</option>
    </select>
  <br><br>
  <select name="topic" id="topic">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Who is requring the bond</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
    <option value="" selected="selected">What jurisdiction is requring the bond</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
     <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your Bond</option>
  </select>
<br><br>

</form>

 <form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" id="date" name="startdate" placeholder="Effective Start Date">

<br><br>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="typeemail" placeholder=" Type E-mail">
</form>

<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: My pictures are lining up to the left vertically]

Answer (score 1):

You are using a lot of positioning that you do not need. In this case the large majority of your issue comes from the .centered class.  I removed some css rules from there.

I also added a flex container around your split divs and removed the fixed positioning from them.

If I were you I would look into display flex and learn how to use it because positioning objects on the page like you are could cause complications later in the project.

I also added display flex to your row class and centered the content from there.

Keep in mind some positioning styles will remove the object from the normal flow of the document.  This is what happened in this case so your images had no idea your text was there because you had an absolute position on your centered class and removed it from the normal flow so the images just ignore the text.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0C133C;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav>li {
  display: Inline-block;
  padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;
}

.nav>li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0C133C;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

.clearer {
  clear: both;
}

.subnav class {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.subnav>div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0C133C;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px 30px 10px 9px;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.subnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.split {
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.centered {
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #282C41;
  color: white;
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 40px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 30;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
  margin-top: .5rem;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  position: relative;
  left: 140px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button: {
  position: relative;
  left: 140px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row .column img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>


    <subnav class="subnav subnav-light bg-light">
      <img src="universallogo.jpg" class="logo" />
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="subnav=brand" href="#">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Bonds</a>
        </a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Report a Claim</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About Us</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Search</a>
      </div>
    </subnav>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="split left">
      <div class="centered">
        <h1>GET YOUR LICENSE & PERMIT BONDS FAST & EASY</h1>
        <p>We provide our Customers with a fast, easy, and secure way to get bonded. Get your Free Quote in minutes.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="rating">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/275" alt="treas">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="split right">


      <form name="form1" id="form1" action="/action_page.php">
        <select name="subject" id="subject">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your State</option>
          <option value="California">California</option>
          <option value="California">Illinois</option>
          <option value="California">Michigan</option>
          <option value="California">Ohio</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <select name="topic" id="topic">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Who is requring the bond</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
          <option value="" selected="selected">What jurisdiction is requring the bond</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your Bond</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

      </form>

      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="text" id="date" name="startdate" placeholder="Effective Start Date">

        <br><br>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="typeemail" placeholder=" Type E-mail">
      </form>

      <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </div>

    </div>
    

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That made them move underneath the text, however, the sizings are off so it makes on image big and the other one small. Do you know how to make them the same size?

Comment: I cannot see the images in the code on here but based on the image I see they are not the same size.  Updated the answer with placeholders and added a pixel value for the height and width under ".row .column img" in the css. I also removed the inline style you had on the images  Keep in mind these are not responsive values and will not change base on screen size.  If you use a percentage it will be based on the size of its parent container which is the .column. The column currently has no set size.